# Remove CSS & JS files from Wordpress Main Page For Increase Pagespeed?

Tags: filters, css, javascript, conditional-tags

With the reference of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463304/wordpress-load-plugin-css-js-in-functions-php-w-conditional-tags answered by @maiorano84

i am using **cforms**, **FancyBox**, **WP Page Numbers** plugins for **Wordpress**. From **Page Speed** point of view i want to remove CSS and JS of these plugin's from all pages except single post page. I also want to put the JS scripts in the footer. below is the code i have been trying but no luck. Would any body help me please?

```
if ( !is_single() ) {
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'my_deregisters', 100 );
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregisters', 100 );

    function my_deregisters() {
        remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_page_numbers_stylesheet');
        wp_deregister_style( 'fancybox' ); 
        wp_deregister_script( 'fancybox' ); 
        wp_dequeue_script('fancybox');      
        wp_dequeue_style('fancybox'); 
        remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'mfbfw_load');
        remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'mfbfw_css');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'mfbfw_init');
        remove_action('wp_head', 'cforms_style');

        }

} else {  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work any better added to a hook with the conditionals inside?

```
function my_deregisters() {

  if ( !is_single() ) {
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_page_numbers_stylesheet');
   //wp_deregister_style( 'fancybox' ); // i think this can be removed
   //wp_deregister_script( 'fancybox' ); // i think this can be removed
   wp_dequeue_script('fancybox');      
   wp_dequeue_style('fancybox'); 
   remove_action('wp_print_scripts', 'mfbfw_load');
   remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'mfbfw_css');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'mfbfw_init');
   remove_action('wp_head', 'cforms_style');
 }

} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregisters', 100 );
```

Comment: thanks @helgatheviking Kathy is Awesome [link](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/)

Comment: You are right. that was the mistake. it is working now but how can i load JS in the **footer** on **single post page**?

Comment: One of the parameters of [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) allows you to load scripts in the footer, so any that are already set to `$in_footer=true` will load in the footer. If that isn't set, you'd have to deregister and reregister with that parameter changed. Seems like a hassle. Try one of the minification plugins (W3 total cache or WP Minify, etc) to combine the scripts and don't worry about them being in the header

Comment: This is great, I have just compiled a set of PHP functions that makes it easier to handle more files using array and then looping over it - https://www.stramaxon.com/2021/10/conditionally-loading-js-css-files-in.html